# winston logger: duplicate lines of same information logged

Tags: javascript, node.js, winston

```
const winston = requires('winston');

const logDir = "./logs/";

function filePath(prefix) {

// get date time for file name
let today = new Date();
let dd = today.getDate();
let mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
let yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if (dd < 10) { dd = '0' + dd; }
if (mm < 10) { mm = '0' + mm; }

// file name format: mm_dd_yyyy_type
let name = mm + '_' + dd + '_' + yyyy + '_' + prefix + '_logs.txt';
let path = logDir + prefix + "-logs/" + name;
return path;
}

const { combine, timestamp, printf } = winston.format;
const logFormat = printf(info => {
      return `${info.timestamp} ${info.level}: ${info.message}`
});

let infoLogger = winston.createLogger({
format: combine(
    timestamp(),
    logFormat
  ),    
exitOnError: false 
});

let info = function (data) {

let infoDir = logDir + "info-logs/";
// create the info log directory if it does not exist
if (!file.existsSync(infoDir)) file.mkdirSync(infoDir);

const fileTransport = new winston.transports.File({
    level: "info",
    filename: filePath("info"),
    handleExceptions: true,
    json: true,
});
infoLogger.add(fileTransport);
infoLogger.info(data);
}
```

this is the code I am using. On my front end I have a form, which sends a request to backend. In the request handler this snippet of code executes:

```
const logger = require("../logger");
logger.info("some info logged");
```

when the server is fired. upon the first request, one line is logged correctly

```
2018-07-11T03:36:24.502Z info: some info logged
```

However, after say sending the request for the third time, this is the results

```
2018-07-11T03:36:24.502Z info: some info logged
2018-07-11T03:36:28.502Z info: some info logged
2018-07-11T03:36:28.502Z info: some info logged
2018-07-11T03:36:35.502Z info: some info logged
2018-07-11T03:36:35.502Z info: some info logged
2018-07-11T03:36:35.502Z info: some info logged
```

As you can notice, the information logged are multiplied according to number of request, ie on third request, three lines were appended to file.

Cannot seem to figure out the issue :/